# Comment on answer if question was moved

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, migration

I wanted to comment on an answer on Stack Overflow. I started typing my comment and hit the "Add Comment" button; however the question was moved to security.stackexchange.com, and I got a message that the comment couldn't be added.

Wouldn't it be possible to add the comment to the moved location instead of requiring me to write the comment again?

Comment: Why do I always get downvoted here on meta? :P

Comment: They mean different things.  As a feature-request people are simply disagreeing with your suggestion, **not** implying you made a bad question, etc.  [See the faq](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: @M. Tibbits: I know. I just don´t understand how someone can downvote on something like this. I would like to know what´s wrong with the idea. In stead of simply downvoting it. That´s why I also added the discussion tag.

Comment: Adding tags doesn't change whether people will downvote. People disagree with this suggestion, and they're going to downvote it to show their opinion. I downvoted it just because you whined about downvotes.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Good for you! I hope it felt good! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would probably make the whole migration process more complicated than it already is.

If you're unlucky enough to hit enter right at that moment when the question is "in flux" between to sites, well, it was just a comment anyway. It should not be such a big deal to type it again.

---

It's more problematic for answers that could have taken some time and energy to write, but then your browser's back button (and the automatic periodic draft saving feature) should restore most of what you had.

Comment: Maybe there could be a notification similar to the one you get when other people have posted an answer?

Comment: Still more complexity, and actually there might already be one (I don't know). The notification that others have posted answers is not synchronous as far as I can tell (probably the browser checking periodically) - it would not save the poster if he hit enter right at the wrong time.

Comment: @Mat: complexity for whom?

Comment: For the devs coding these stackexchange sites.

Comment: @Mat: So? Don't think that is the rule: if it's complex we are not doing it... :)

Comment: Of course that's not the rule. If it's complex but adds value, it should be considered. If it's complex but adds very little value, it shouldn't be considered. I don't think what you are proposing adds enough value to make the tradeoff interesting. (But this is my opinion, others are free to chime in - maybe it's not as complicated  as I think it could be.)

Answer (score -1):

1. Write a comment.
2. Notice that the question has been migrated, and you're unable to post said comment.
3. Decide if the comment is still relevant (i.e., if you were about to post that you think the question belongs on a different site, and it's already been moved there, don't post your comment).
4. If your comment *is* still relevant: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.
5. Click the link to visit the question on the new site: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.
6. Problem solved.

** <sup>If you're on a Mac or Unix-based machine, change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to the appropriate modifier key for your platform.</sup>

Pay special attention to the note in number 3. This is why this feature request will never be implemented. We don't *want* people posting the same comments they were about to post on one site after the question is migrated to another site. More often than not, the comment is made irrelevant, or at a minimum, it needs to be modified to fit the question's new home.

Comment: I didn't got the chance of copy-pasting since the message was gone. Also backspace (back button) didn't work for me.